# What does '...' mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was reviewing some alternative solutions in a codewars kata and came across this line in the 'top' solution:

```
result.push(...algo(numbers[i]));
```

What is the purpose of the '...' in this context? I haven't seen this before and can't find any reference to it anywhere.

Is this a new feature in ES6?

If you need more context it was the 'Split all even numbers to odd ones in different ways' kata, and was the solution by the user 'ph0en1x'.

Don't want to post the whole code here for fear of spoiling the challenge for any other potential users.

Thanks if anyone is able to help clarify!

Comment: It's [*spread syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), there has to be a dupetarget...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an ES6 feature, called `spread` operator.

It's mean is that you have an array object like this `[1,2,3]` and have a function that takes in 3 parameters, you don't need to pass like `func(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2])`. You can just spread `func(...arr)` the array and it will do the same instead of you.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];

function func(a,b,c){
  console.log(a); // arr[0]
  console.log(b); // arr[1]
  console.log(c); // arr[2]
}

func(...arr);
```

Comment: you should metion the other meaning as rest syntax as well.

Comment: The rest is another feautre, isn't it?. It is going to the function declaration, not the call

Comment: it uses the same dots.

Comment: I know the rest operator. It is going to the function declaration, not the call. `spread` operator it related to the call

Comment: Thanks for your help, Im still learning es5 JavaScript. I need to start becoming more aware of es6 and beyond!